# Retrieve the date from my database and display it in Android Studio

Tags: php, android, sql, web-services, objectmapper

My application is to display the time the marker was put. I can save and recover the position but not the time. In my database I created a column with datetime, but I can not get the dates and display them in a string.

This is my php code :

```
    $statement = $database->prepare("SELECT latitude as lat, longitude as lng FROM Marqueur");
    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json = json_encode($results);
    echo($json);
```

This is my activity :

```
public void success(String data, int idRequest) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            this.persoMarkerList = objectMapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<List<PersoMarker>>(){});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        switch (idRequest){
            case 1 :{
                for (PersoMarker persomarker : this.persoMarkerList) {
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(persomarker.getLat(), persomarker.getLng());
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                            .title("I'm here at :")); /* I want show the date here */
         }
```

and my method who manage my webservice :

```
    public void requestGet(String target, List<Pair<String, String>> param){
        Fuel.INSTANCE.get(URL + target, param).responseString(this);
```

My class PersoMarker :

```
public class PersoMarker {

    private double lat;
    private double lng;

// getter and setter
```

Comment: are you getting the lat and long in the response ?

Comment: Yes for this i have any problems. I show you my class PersoMarker who takes this values

Comment: if the 'dates' are from the same dbtable you can add "SELECT dates as dates , latitude as lat, longitude as lng FROM Marqueur" as try to get it in the PersoMarker

Comment: Ok it's good, I just had to get the date in string. I tried with calendar (my teacher who told me to put calendar if I have to change later). Thanks Jacks.

Comment: ok, so did you get the response in string now ?

Comment: Yes i got the answer in string.

Comment: are you able to add time in this line too? , googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                            .title("I'm here at :"));

Comment: Yes, i added : + persomarker.getdate() after my title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks all good few modification are required in order to achieve the requiremen.
PHP code should be like below, if the dates are saved in the same dbtable.

```
$statement = $database->prepare("SELECT dates as dates, latitude as lat, longitude as lng FROM Marqueur");
    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json = json_encode($results);
    echo($json);
```

Activity code should look like below

```
 switch (idRequest){
            case 1 :{
                for (PersoMarker persomarker : this.persoMarkerList) {
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(persomarker.getLat(), persomarker.getLng());
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                            .title("I'm here at :"+persomarker.getDate())); /* Added date String */
         }
```

Pojo class should be something like this

```
 public class PersoMarker {

        private double lat;
        private double lng;
        private String dates;

// geter / setter
```

Good luck!